# Replace string using XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xls

I'm having some problems replacing a string within a string using XSL 1.0. I've read various threads on this site and others but just can't put my finger on why my method will not work. For the purposes of this question I've dumbed down the data a little but you'll get the jist, hopefully.

So, I've got my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="replaceAString.xsl"?>
<Body>
    <aString>textToReplace</aString>
</Body>
```

and XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>
       <xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/>
    </h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="myVar">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Body/aString/" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'textToReplace'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'withThisText'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was hoping that the result of this transformation would be the text "withThisText" appearing within a heading1 HTML tag. Unfortunately I'm getting nothing back. This is one of those things where I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my logic. I'm no XML/XSL professional but I'm not a complete novice either. Although I'm sure someone will pull me up on this now :P

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm really stuck here :(

Many thanks,

James

Comment: You are not actually *transforming* anything. Is that what you want? You have a `with-param` that is not inside a `call-templates` or `apply-templates` and some unprefixed XSL tags (`template`). You processor is probably printing out error messages (see the console of your browser). What do they say?

Comment: @helderdarocha "*some unprefixed XSL tags (`template`).*" Where do you see that?

Comment: @michael.hor257k It seemed to me that the first `template` was unprefixed. The post may have been edited, or I was mistaken about it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342565/why-is-my-xslt-here-stripping-html-tags/21345359#21345359 for an example (one of many) of a string-replacing template.

Comment: @helderdarocha You are quite right. I did have some unprefixed template tags which I'd edited as soon I realised I'd made the mistake.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks, Michael. I'll take a look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, change:

```
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="Body/aString/" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="Body/aString" />
```

Next, note that within the first `<xsl:when>` you have:

```
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
```

I believe this needs to be part of `<xsl:call-template>`?

Answer (score 6):

Right, I've sorted it guys!! My replace template was slightly incorrect, I must admit so thanks for pointing that out. Thanks to @helderdarocha for advising me to use the console to troubleshoot. I did this and found that much Stylesheet couldn't even be parsed!! The cause of this issue? check out my xmlns:xsl namespace declaration; no "www.". With this corrected and a change to my code, the replace function is now working a treat :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="**http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform**">

<xsl:variable name="myVar">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Body/aString" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'textToReplace'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'withThisText'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/>
    </h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" 
                    select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Many thanks!!

Regards,

James